# Bindablebase for desktop apps

Tags: c#, windows

I am trying to port over a class from a Windows Store App (Since there is not Kinect Support for the store we have to make a desktop app).
I am running into problems with the following libraries not being found (guessing Windows Store Specific)

```
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.UI;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging;
```

I was able to fix most if the Media stuff, however I'm stuck trying to find the equivalent of bindablebase and `[Windows.Foundation.Metadata.WebHostHidden]`. Also all of the `this.SetProperty` calls are failing (due to linking errors since there are the wrong libraries).
Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Eh? What does `calls are failing` even mean?

Comment: The libraries aren't being found because they are Store specific.

Comment: @FrankSposaro: define: `to fail`. Exception? Compilation error? Silent crash? Store submission failure? BSOD? WHAT does "fail" mean? I really mean no aggresion. I just scream we need facts and descriptions :)

Comment: Is everyone out to troll me? The methods aren't being found because I don't have the correct libraries. They are Windows Store Apps libs and I need the equivalent for the desktop apps

Comment: Just create a class that implements INotifyPropertyChanged and add a method SetProperty<T>. the implementation can be found here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xx130657.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't been able to find the equivalent of Bindablabase for the desktop apps, however I found a work around.

Instead of using Bindablebase you just have to use INotifyCollectionChanged directly. I believe that the BB class also implements this and just wraps it. So instead of calling SetProperty which is in BB, you have to call PropertyChanged manually.